# Powershell Separate csv data into separate rows

Tags: excel, powershell, format

I have the following script and it gets me the info I need.

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$LogFile = "d:\monitors.csv"

"Manufacturer,Name,Serial" | Out-File $LogFile

ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
    $Manufacturer = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName|where {$_ -ne 0}|ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $Name = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName  |where {$_ -ne 0}| ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $Serial = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID  |where {$_ -ne 0}| ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""

    "$Manufacturer,$Name,$Serial" | Out-File $LogFile -append
}
```

My problem is the data is exported to the excel spreadsheet like this..

> > Manufacturer,Name,Serial.
> >
> > ACI,VE248,K8LMQS048382
>
> HWP,HP P232,6CM8122DXL
>
> HWP,HP P232,6CM7241DRB

I need it to be:

```
Manufacturer   Name   Serial
```

in the spreadsheet, and when I do the next pc, it adds to the next line and so on.

I have looked online and the examples just don't match.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Why not just using [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)?: `Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi |Select-Object Manufacturer, Name, Serial |Export-Csv -append $LogFile`

Comment: When I run it, I get this on the first line #TYPE Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject and when I run it again, it deletes the info instead of adding it to the next line......

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but when I run, all 3 of the model numbers are the same. Does this need tweeked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already commented, use `Export-Csv` to write out the wanted data in csv format, rather than constructing it manually.
That means your ForEach-Object loop should emit **objects** instead of lines of concatenated strings.

Also, nowadays, I would use the newer `Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WmiObject` ([What's the difference](https://www.ipswitch.com/blog/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference))

Try

```
$LogFile = "d:\monitors.csv"
Get-CimInstance -ClassName WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Manufacturer = [string]::new($_.ManufacturerName, 0, $_.ManufacturerName.Length).Trim("`0")
        Name         = [string]::new($_.UserFriendlyName, 0, $_.UserFriendlyName.Length).Trim("`0")
        Serial       = [string]::new($_.SerialNumberID, 0, $_.SerialNumberID.Length).Trim("`0")
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

<sup>The `-UseCulture` switch makes sure the output csv file uses the same delimiter characters your locally installed Excel would expect, so you can simply double-click the file to open it in Excel</sup>